# Record and playback simultaneously - Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, playback, channel

I am trying to build an application where I am required to record and playback simultaneously. The application needs to go live on an asterisk telephony server. My problem is:

1. A user calls the asterisk server and starts to speak.
2. The voice packets being sent by the user are recorded in a wav file on the system.
3. A copy of the voice packets are sent as feedback simultaneously.

I have taken a look at `ChanSpy`, but it will not work if one is using `Record`.

My questions:
1. If a user calls an asterisk server, does that channel become a `simplex` or `half-duplex` channel?
2. Are there any commands etc. that allow us to do the above?
3. If not, does that mean I need to go into `C` programming for asterisk (`agi-bin`)?

P.S: Please let me know in case more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try MixMonitor? That allows you to record the call, and doesn't interfere with ChanSpy usage. ChanSpy IS the best way to do this, by the way.

Comment: thanks for the reply. `MixMonitor` allows me to record the channel. I am still unable to mix the incoming channel and then feed it back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to feed to voice channel from the caller *back to the same caller* correct?

Have you tried the [Echo](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Echo) command?

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thanks for the suggestion. It does seem to work nicely. Just one question though. When I speak into the phone, the echo stops after the first few seconds and there is complete silence then on. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Yeah, the echo test only runs for a period of time.  I'm not sure if this is configurable, but you should otherwise be able to keep looping the call back into echo in your call flow